# How to mount disk at startup in RancherOS?

Tags: rancher

How to mount disk at startup in RancherOS?

I tried fstab like this:

```
/dev/sdb2       /mnt/data       ext4    defaults        0       0
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but you need to add some config to your cloud-config.yml; something like:

```
mounts:
 - [ sdb2, /mnt/data ]
```

http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#adjust-mount-points-mounted